# Web API ResponseType for Single Integer

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

What is the "correct" way to have a call to a Web API REST service that simply returns a single integer?

I have no requirements here in terms of XML, JSON, or anything else.  The call to the service just needs to return an integer.

Do I use the `ResponseType` attribute here?

I have the service return type as `HttpResponseMessage`, and for services such as something returning JSON I would set the Content property on this to `StringContent` with UTF8 "application/json".

But what is correct for a single integer?

Comment: A single number is also [valid JSON](http://json.org/), so you could totally just return a number and serve that as JSON. Or wrap it in some object with maybe a `Result` property.

Comment: I may just do that.  With no strict implementation requirements here, I can get that done in 30 seconds.  I have other Web API REST methods in this project that are returning JSON.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend that you use the IHttpActionResult type for your API methods. It will allow you to use several different convenience methods for returning common responses. In your case it would just look like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetInteger() {
   // Ok is a convenience method for returning a 200 Ok response
   return Ok(1);
}
```

or if you wanted to return it wrapped in an object for easier JSON consumption an anonymous object is fine:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetInteger() {
   // Ok is a convenience method for returning a 200 Ok response
   return Ok(new {
      value = 1
   });
}
```

[Documentation here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results)

Summarized from the docs are some of the reasons why you would use IHttpActionResult:

- Simplifies unit testing your controllers.
- Moves common logic for creating HTTP responses into separate classes.
- Makes the intent of the controller action clearer, by hiding the low-level details of constructing the response.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into IHttpActionResult.  There are so many code samples with Web API doing everything different, but the one common thing seems to be returning HttpResponseMessage.  I need to go with best practices for this.  I did come across this article that says "Assuming you’ve read the above article it is recommended to use IHttpActionResult."... http://thuru.net/2015/02/20/httpresponsemessage-vs-ihttpactionresult/

Comment: IHttpActionResult is just an abstraction over top of the HttpResponseMessage that makes it easier to use :) If you need to construct a response manually you can still do so while returning IHttpActionResult using the ResponseMessageResult. More info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.results.aspx

Comment: I now like to convert my existing methods that return JSON to use IHttpActionResult.  How do you convert something like this?  `Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { User = person });`?  I see there is a `return Json(result);` whiich results in `HTTP 200 OK`.  Is this the correct way to go?

Comment: You can just use Ok() for anything that would have used HttpStatusCode.OK before. So you would just do return Ok(new { User = person });

Comment: @Jessecater I opened a new question on this subject, because I'm intrigued but the attempts I've tried on one of my more complex JSON methods is failing using `IHttpActionResult`.  Any help over there would be appreciated, thanks.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36241098/ihttpactionresult-with-json-string

Answer (score 3):

Well, depending on what you wanted to response body to look like.  Just a number:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "1");
```

A JSON object containing the number:

```
var myNumber = new
{
    theNumber = 1
};
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, myNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own content type deriving from `HttpContent` class, which is marked as `abstract`.

`StringContent` derives indirectly from it by inheriting from `ByteArrayContent`.

Generally it depends on the real "meaning" of your `int`. If this is some kind of an identifier, I'd wrap it into some kind of an object.

Comment: It's simply the depth of a binary tree.  So if the lowest node in the tree is at level 61 I need to just return 61.

Comment: @Patrick As far as I know, there is no `IntResponse` in WebAPI for now. If you care about special handling of your `int`, you can use my advice, other good options have been introduced already.