# Get id of last Rest API POST using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, rest, xamarin

I need to be able to access the id of a new Post.  I will be using this id to populate another field called LocationId like this: "L" + id = LocationId (example L22) where 22 is the id of the new Post.  Here is the code for my Post request:

```
private async void BtnSubmit_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var imageArray = FilesHelper.ReadFully(file.GetStream());
        file.Dispose();

        var location = new Models.Location()
        {               
            LocationName = EntName.Text,
            ImageArray = imageArray,
        };
        ApiServices apiServices = new ApiServices();
        bool response = await apiServices.PostLocation(location);

        bool response2 = await apiServices.InputLocationId(id, location);
        if (!response || !response2)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Something wrong", "Cancel");
        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Hi", "Your record has beed added successfully", "Alright");
        }
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new SetupPage());
```

This is on the client side.  I have all the APIs created (such as PostLocation and InputLocationId)on Azure SQL Server.  This is for a mobile inventory app built using Xamarin.

```
public async Task<bool> PostLocation(Location location)
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(location);
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", Settings.AccessToken);
        var wimsApiUrl = "http://xxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/Locations";
        //Get the Body of the Post
        var body = await httpClient.PostAsync(wimsApiUrl, content);
        //Convert it to a string
        var jString = await body.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        //Place it in a JSON Object
        JObject joResponse = JObject.Parse(jString);
        //Parse the JSON Object into an Int from a String
        var id = int.Parse(joResponse["Id"].ToString());
        //This is used in my other script to Put the LocationId of Lxx
        AddNewLocationPage.NewLocationId = id;

        return body.IsSuccessStatusCode;


    }
```

My Post Location API:

```
// POST: api/Locations
    [ResponseType(typeof(Location))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostLocation([FromBody] Location location)
    {
        string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        var stream = new MemoryStream(location.ImageArray);
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var file = String.Format("{0}.jpg", guid);
        var folder = "~/Content/Images";
        var fullPath = String.Format("{0}/{1}", folder, file);
        var response = FilesHelper.UploadPhoto(stream, folder, file);
        if (response)
        {
            location.ImagePath = fullPath;
        }
        var newLocation = new Location()
        {
            LocationName = location.LocationName,
            User = userId,
            ImagePath = location.ImagePath

        };
        db.Locations.Add(newLocation);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Ok(new { newLocation.Id});
    }
```

I will then take the id and put it in this Put Request to create the LocationId:

```
public async Task<bool> InputLocationId(int id, Location location)
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(location);
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", Settings.AccessToken);
        var wimsApiUrl = "http://xxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/Locations/InputLocationId/";
        var completeUrl = String.Format("{0}{1}", wimsApiUrl, id);
        var response = await httpClient.PutAsync(completeUrl, content);
        return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
    }
```

The InputLocationId API will automatically create the LocationId.  Here is my API:

```
// PUT: api/Locations/5
    [HttpPut]
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    [Route("api/Locations/InputLocationId/{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult InputLocationId(int id, [FromBody] Location location)
    {
        //string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var result = db.Locations.FirstOrDefault(locationId => locationId.Id == id);
        var resultant = String.Format("L{0}", id);

        location.LocationName = location.LocationName;
        result.LocationId = resultant;

        db.SaveChanges();
        return Ok("The record has been updated");
    }
```

I am simply stuck on how to access that id!

Comment: why don't you have PostLocation return the ID of the new location?

Comment: Would that be in the PostLocation API on the server side or the PostLocation on the client side?  I need it to use it on the client side for the next Put request.  What would the syntax be? (thanks for the response)

Comment: the server would need to return the ID to the client.  I believe that after you call SaveChanges you can just check the ID property of your model.

Comment: I modified the // POST: api/Locations to add "int newId = location.Id;" after the SaveChanges.  How to I access this on the client side?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36240455/web-api-responsetype-for-single-integer

Comment: You don't want int location.Id, you'll want newLocation.Id. That is the Entity associated to the DbContext. I recommend *not* passing entities back & forth between client and server. You should validate all data sent to the server to ensure that it is valid for the particular request and has not been altered maliciously by a client via debugger or man-in-middle.

Comment: return Ok(new { newLocation.Id});   This is working and in the Postman Body I receive {"Id":22}. How do I access this return value (newLocation.Id) on the client so that it can be sent in a Put request immediately afterwards?  This newLocation.Id will be combined with "L" to give a "L22" which will denote that it is a location rather than something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returns need to be converted into a string from the HttpResponseMessage.

```
var body = await httpClient.PostAsync(wimsApiUrl, content);
var jString = await body.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Then we can place it into a JSON Object:

```
JObject joResponse = JObject.Parse(jString);
```

Now this JSON Object can be parsed into an Int.  Note it needs to be converted to a string.

```
var id = int.Parse(joResponse["Id"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// get the response body
var body = await httpClient.PostAsync(wimsApiUrl, content);

// load it into a JSON object using Newtonsoft
JObject data = JObject.Parse(body);

// get the id
var id = int.Parse(data["id"]);
```

Comment: You got me on the right track with the bread crumbs.  I learned a lot over the past two days so thanks for that.  Just had to ensure that the data was in the right format.